# Easy way to apply Joomla template styling to my own content

Tags: css, joomla, themes

I have an application that is mainly a bunch of PHP files included in a Joomla! application by Jumi.  I want to make the site look nicer, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.  There is a RocketTheme template installed on the site, and I'd like to be able to leverage it or some of the other CSS used alongside it.

Specifically, I want to decorate tables.  Should I search for and include CSS classes directly into my tags by searching through the template's classes, or is there a framework I could use that automatically adds the right classes based on the current theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla had some default class names and styles that are generic and used by most templates.
In order to have template-specific views (or, to be more precise, adapted versions of the views), overrides are added, in order to avoid changing the original source. Those can be found under the template's `/html` subdirectory.

The other element used for styling sections is the style property typically used with `jdoc` clauses in the template's main page: `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="foo" style="xhtml" />`.
These provide the content with a wrapping that matches the overall feel of the template.

Plenty of material about those subjects can be found on the Joomla! developer community website and in various books (most are well worth the money).